# Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my cs:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
            {
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;               
                Textid.Text = gr.Cells[0].Text;
                Textusername.Text = gr.Cells[1].Text;
                Textclass.Text = gr.Cells[2].Text;
                Textsection.Text = gr.Cells[3].Text;
                Textaddress.Text = gr.Cells[4].Text;
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
            {
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;      
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gr.Cells[0].Text);
                var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                GridView1.DeleteRow(id);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

I created student details form, I want to delete the row from `gridview`.

When i click delete, it shows following error:

> Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless DeleteCommand is specified.

I'm new to .net. Now getting started,

May i know, what is my mistake in the above code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
    {
        GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;      
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gr.Cells[0].Text);
        var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        //comment or remove below line
        //GridView1.DeleteRow(id);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //rebind the data after delete
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: thanks, its working, may  i know, what is "var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());? can you explain?

Comment: which part of that line you couldn't understand?

Comment: e.CommandArgument will give you the value which set as CommandArgument in the gridview for the current command, here you have set ID of the record as delete command argument. to set the parameter value you have converted it to a integer value.

Comment: you can find msdn documentation all these and also google will help you to find many examples and valuable resources.  as beginner you better try to learn them and find answers yourself first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93849/discussion-between-rani-and-damith).